# How to keep login name same when migrating users from local SQL Server to Azure Active Directory B2C

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, identity-management

I am migrating local users from SQL database to Azure AD B2C. Azure AD uses user principle name (UPN) by default for login. I have gone through below documentation but not able to understand how can I configure Azure AD to use my existing username as alternate login. I also need to update password for each user upon first login. It is a web application where I want to shift user authentication to Azure AD B2C by redirecting app users to a customized microsoft login page.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-migration

https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/user-migration

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating the user, see this [sample](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/user-migration/blob/master/seamless-account-migration/script/Pre-MigrationHelper.ps1).

You put the users username in the `issuerAssignedId` value.

```
  "identities": [
    {
      "signInType": "emailAddress",
      "issuer": "b2cprod.onmicrosoft.com",
      "issuerAssignedId": "jsmith@yahoo.com"
    }
```

On a raw attribute level, this is called `signInNames.[signInType]`. You will see it referred as `signInNames.X` in the Custom Policy.